# How to maintain two different masters in a single GIT repository

Tags: git, git-branch

How can I maintain two different masters (HEADS) in a single GIT repository?

Comment: Why would you want to do this?

Comment: Are you really asking how to have two different _branches_ in a repository? One could be named "master," and the other named something else.

Comment: currently in cvs repository we r maintaining two sub modules(two heads) in a single repository. I want to use the same feature in GIT.

Answer (score 0):

As reading the comments, I understand that you need to create a second branch.
To do so use:

```
git checkout -b new_branch
```

To get back to the first branch use:

```
git checkout old_branch
```

You can get more information [here](https://github.com/Kunena/Kunena-Forum/wiki/Create-a-new-branch-with-git-and-manage-branches).

Comment: I don't want two branches. I am looking to have two different heads with two irrelevant code in the same repository.

Comment: A branch is the same thing as a head. In git, a branch is just a head commit. When you commit to a branch, the new commit becomes the new head of the branch.

Answer (score 0):

HEAD is simply a pointer to the commit that your current directory reflects, so it really makes no sense to talk of a git repository having "two heads". If you want two *branches* that are totally unrelated to each other, what you really want are two **roots**, i.e. parentless commits. To create a new root, unrelated to what you are currently on, you would do the following:

```
git checkout --orphan project2   
git rm -rf .                     #removes all the old stuff you were working on
```

Now you can add whatever files you want and commit them, and the `project2` branch will be totally unrelated to your previous branch.

Comment: I don't want two branches. I am looking to have two different heads with two irrelevant code in the same repository.

Comment: Edited the answer. You will still be using two git branches, but they will be totally unrelated to each other.

Comment: But i want to use the same name for both the branches.